# How can I avoid multiple functions which do the same thing with different types C++

Tags: c++

I have a C++ class which is for an OpenGL Buffer, it has many many `setData()` functions to account for the different types of data the buffer could contain e.g for ints:

```
void Buffer::setData(int* data)
{
    //Bind the buffer
    bind();

    //Input the data into the buffer based on the type
    glBufferData(type, sizeof(int) * size, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
```

This is the same for every version of the function then only thing which changes is the `sizeof(int)` becomes `sizeof(<other type>)`

I was wondering if there's a way around this? One possibility I considered is a generic type variable such as var? I know var itself doesn't exist in C++ but is there some equivalent?

Comment: Won't templates work??

Comment: Not sure how to use templates I'm a bit of a C++ novice, I'll look into it though :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A template function would probably serve you well. The method:

```
template< typename T > void Buffer::setData(T data)
{
    //Bind the buffer
    bind();

    //Input the data into the buffer based on the type
    glBufferData(type, sizeof(T) * size, data, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
}
```

defines a family of methods, one for every type `T`. Of course, it might not actually *work* for all types `T`, but fortunately C++ will only complain when you call it with an incompatible type.

Comment: Thank you! I love the internet sometimes :)

Comment: Ahh I'm having a bit of trouble defining this template in the header function just adding the template bit and updating the type doesn't seem to work?

Comment: Ah, yes. Template declaration vs definition is tricky. I'd move the entire method to the header file (i.e. replace your declaration in the header with that definition).

Comment: Yeah I've done that thanks :) Not ideal since every other function is defined in the .cpp file but still much better than having all those other functions, thanks again!